# Crime statistics homework assistance

Tags: java

I am trying to get this to work but it keeps saying the file is unfindable when you type the location.. I want the user to be able to put the location of the file that is needed to be read.  I cannot figure out how to stop the errors.  Any help would be appreciated.  The output allows me to type a file location but after that it errors.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class CrimeStatistics {

    // instantiate List object - it is static since all instances will use the same data
    private static List<CrimeDataObjects> recordList = new ArrayList<CrimeDataObjects>(); 

    // constructor
    public CrimeStatistics() {

    }

    //static block to call compile data and fill List - used in all methods
    static{ 
    CrimeDataRecords.readData();
    recordList = CrimeDataRecords.getDataRecords();
    }

    /*
     * popGrowthRate method - compiles and displays population growth year to year
     */
    public ArrayList<String> popGrowthRate () {

        //declare variables
        String tempYears; // temporarily holds year value
        double tempGrowth; //stores the growth percent
        String yearToYearGrowth;

        ArrayList<String> growthRateChart = new ArrayList<String>();//array to hold data from CrimeDataRecords

        // add header to array
        growthRateChart.add("**** Year to Year ****");
        growthRateChart.add("**** Growth Rates ****");
        growthRateChart.add("----------------------");

        for (int i = 0; i < recordList.size()-1; i++){ // Loop through List of CrimeDataObjects
            tempYears = Integer.toString(recordList.get(i).getYear()); // get year and store in variable
            tempYears += " - "; // add String to variable
            tempYears += Integer.toString(recordList.get(i+1).getYear());   // get next year and add to variable
            tempGrowth = (((recordList.get(i+1).getPoplulation() -        
                            recordList.get(i).getPoplulation()) /
                           (recordList).get(i).getPoplulation()))*100; // calculate growth and add to variable

            yearToYearGrowth = String.format("%s = %.4f%%" ,tempYears, tempGrowth);// form string for year to year growth
            growthRateChart.add(yearToYearGrowth); // add string to arrayList   
        }// end for loop

        return growthRateChart;
    }// end popGrowthRate method

    /*
    * murderRateHigh method - outputs highest year and rate
    */
    public String murderRateHigh () {

        // declare variables
        int year = 0;
        float highestRate = 0;
        String murderRateHigh = "\n**** Highest Murder Rate ****" +
                                "\n-----------------------------\n" +
                                "Year: ";

        year = recordList.get(0).getYear();// store year of first record
        highestRate = recordList.get(0).getMurderNonNegManslaughterRate();//store rate of first record

        // loop through records and compare rates
        for( int i = 1; i < recordList.size(); i++ ){           
            if(highestRate < recordList.get(i).getMurderNonNegManslaughterRate() ){ //if rate is higher
                year = recordList.get(i).getYear();// store year
                highestRate = recordList.get(i).getMurderNonNegManslaughterRate();//store rate
            }// end if  
        }// end for loop

        murderRateHigh += Integer.toString(year); //add year to string
        murderRateHigh += "  Murder Rate:";// add title to string
        murderRateHigh += Float.toString(highestRate);// add murder rate to string

        return murderRateHigh;
    }// end murderRateHigh method

    /* 
     * murderRateLow method - outputs lowest year and rate
     */
    public String murderRateLow () {

        // declare variables
                int year = 0;
                float highestRate = 0;
                String murderRateLow = "\n**** Lowest Murder Rate ****" +
                                       "\n-----------------------------\n" +
                                       "Year: ";

                year = recordList.get(0).getYear();// store year of first record
                highestRate = recordList.get(0).getMurderNonNegManslaughterRate();//store rate of first record
                // loop through records and compare rates
                for( int i = 1; i < recordList.size(); i++ ){   
                    if(highestRate > recordList.get(i).getMurderNonNegManslaughterRate() ){ //if rate is lower
                        year = recordList.get(i).getYear();// store year
                        highestRate = recordList.get(i).getMurderNonNegManslaughterRate();//store rate
                    }// end if  
                }// end for loop

                murderRateLow += Integer.toString(year); //add year to string
                murderRateLow += "  Murder Rate:";// add title to string
                murderRateLow += Float.toString(highestRate);// add murder rate to string
                //murderRateLow += yearLow;

                return murderRateLow;

    }// end murderRateLow method

    /*
    * robberyRateHigh method - outputs highest year and rate
    */
    public String robberyRateHigh () {

        // declare variables
        int year = 0;
        float highestRate = 0;
        String robberyRateHigh = "\n**** Highest Robbery Rate ****" +
                                 "\n-----------------------------\n";

        year = recordList.get(0).getYear();// store year of first record
        highestRate = recordList.get(0).getRobberyRate();//store rate of first record

        // loop through records and compare rates
        for( int i = 1; i < recordList.size(); i++ ){   
            if(highestRate < recordList.get(i).getRobberyRate() ){ //if rate is higher
                year = recordList.get(i).getYear();// store year
                highestRate = recordList.get(i).getRobberyRate();//store rate
            }// end if  
        }// end for loop

        robberyRateHigh += Integer.toString(year); //add year to string
        robberyRateHigh += "  Robbery Rate:";// add title to string
        robberyRateHigh += Float.toString(highestRate);// add murder rate to string

        return robberyRateHigh;
    }// end robberyRateHigh method

    /*
    * robberyRateLow method - outputs lowest year and rate
    */
    public String robberyRateLow () {

        // declare variables
        int year = 0;
        float highestRate = 0;
        String robberyRateLow = "\n**** Lowest Robbery Rate ****" +
                                "\n-----------------------------\n";

        year = recordList.get(0).getYear();// store year of first record
        highestRate = recordList.get(0).getRobberyRate();// store rate of first record

        // loop through records and compare rates
        for( int i = 1; i < recordList.size(); i++ ){           
            if(highestRate > recordList.get(i).getRobberyRate() ){ //if rate is lower
                year = recordList.get(i).getYear();// store year
                highestRate = recordList.get(i).getRobberyRate();//store rate
            }// end if  
        }// end for loop

        robberyRateLow += Integer.toString(year); //add year to string
        robberyRateLow += "  Robbery Rate:";// add title to string
        robberyRateLow += Float.toString(highestRate);// add murder rate to string

        return robberyRateLow;
    }// end robberyRateLow method

}// end CrimeStatistics class

/*required imports*/
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


/* 
 * CrimeDataRecords class - manages all CSV data extraction
 *                              and build records
 */
public class CrimeDataRecords {

    // declare Objects
    private static BufferedReader fileIn; //BufferedReader to read csv file 
    private static List<CrimeDataObjects> dataRecords; // List to store CrimeDataObjects

    /* default constructor*/
    public CrimeDataRecords() {

    }

    /*
     * compileData method - extract data from csv and pass to buidCrimeDataRecords
     */
    public static void readData(){

        //declare variables
        String lineIn = null; // temporarily holds string from csv file

        //initialize objects
        UserInterface userFile; 

        try {   
            // instantiate Objects
            userFile = new UserInterface();
            fileIn = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(userFile.getFileToRead()));// get file path
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }// end try/catch

        // instantiate List object
        dataRecords = new ArrayList<CrimeDataObjects>();

        try{           
            fileIn.readLine();// skip first line
            lineIn = fileIn.readLine();//read line and store temporary String

            /*while loop to read all lines from CSV file*/
            while(lineIn != null){ //while the next line is not empty   

                //System.out.println(lineIn); uncomment to see data transfer in console

                String[] parsedData = lineIn.split(",");//split strings and store to String array
                buildCrimeDataObjects(parsedData); // call method and pass string array 
                lineIn = fileIn.readLine();// read next line and store to temporary String  

            }//end while loop

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//end try/catch

    }// end compileData method

    /*
     * buildCrimeDataRecords - builds CrimeDataObjects and stores them in List dataRecords
     */
    public static void buildCrimeDataObjects(String[] parsedData){
        String[] data = parsedData;

        // initialize object
        CrimeDataObjects csvRecord;

        // parse strings to correct data type
        int year = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
        long poplulation = Long.parseLong(data[1]);
        long violentCrime = Long.parseLong(data[2]);
        float violentCrimeRate = Float.parseFloat(data[3]); 
        int murderNonNegManslaughter = Integer.parseInt(data[4]);
        float murderNonNegManslaughterRate = Float.parseFloat(data[5]);
        int rape = Integer.parseInt(data[6]);
        float rapeRate = Float.parseFloat(data[7]);
        int robbery = Integer.parseInt(data[8]);
        float robberyRate = Float.parseFloat(data[9]);
        int aggravatedAssault = Integer.parseInt(data[10]);
        float aggravatedAssaultRate = Float.parseFloat(data[11]);
        int propertyCrime = Integer.parseInt(data[12]);
        float propertyCrimeRate = Float.parseFloat(data[13]);
        int burglery = Integer.parseInt(data[14]); 
        float burgleryRate = Float.parseFloat(data[15]);
        int larceny = Integer.parseInt(data[16]);
        float larcenyRate = Float.parseFloat(data[17]);
        int motorVehicleTheft = Integer.parseInt(data[18]);
        float motorVehicleTheftRate = Float.parseFloat(data[19]);    

        // instantiate CrimeDataRecords object and pass data parsed from csv
        csvRecord = new CrimeDataObjects(year,poplulation,violentCrime,violentCrimeRate,murderNonNegManslaughter,
                                         murderNonNegManslaughterRate,rape,rapeRate,robbery,robberyRate,
                                         aggravatedAssault,aggravatedAssaultRate,propertyCrime,propertyCrimeRate,
                                         burglery,burgleryRate,larceny,larcenyRate,motorVehicleTheft,motorVehicleTheftRate);  

        dataRecords.add(csvRecord);// add csvRecord object to List

    }// end buildCrimeDataRecords


    /*
     * getdataRecord method - returns data records as a List
     *                        it is static since all instances use the same data
     */
    public static List<CrimeDataObjects> getDataRecords(){  
        return dataRecords;
    }// end getDataRecors method

}// end Class

/*Required imports*/
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

/* 
 * UserInterface class- creates all user prompts, collects user input and 
 *                      calls methods to display statistics selected.
 */
public class UserInterface {

    // declare variables
    private static String fileToRead = ""; //file path 
    private double startTime = 0.0; //timer start time
    private double endTime = 0.0; //timer end time
    private final String CLEANSPACE = "\n\n\n"; //used to create space in data output 
    Scanner input; 

    //default constructor
    public UserInterface(){ 
    }

    // constructor with file path argument  
    public UserInterface(String filePath) { 
        setFileToRead(filePath);// call method to set file path
    }

    /* 
     * getter method for fileToRead
     */
    public String getFileToRead() { 
        return fileToRead;
    }

    /* 
     * setter method for fileToRead
     * re formats file path for specific OS.
     */
    public void setFileToRead(String filePath) {

        // declare local variable
        String file = filePath;

        //get OS file separator an rebuild file path string
        char separator = java.io.File.separatorChar;//get system default file separator 
        if(separator != '/'){ // if file separator is not / (if Windows)
            String windowsFilePath = file.replace('/', '\\');
            filePath = windowsFilePath;
        }//end if separator != '\'

        // set fileToRead variable with file path
        fileToRead  = file;

    }// end setFileToRead method


    /*
     * setter method for startTime
     */
    public void setStartTime() {
        this.startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }// end setStartTime method

    /*
     * getter method for startTime
     */
    public double getStartTime() { 
        return startTime;
    }// end getStartTime method

    /*
     * setter method for endTime
     */
    public void setEndTime() {
        this.endTime = System.nanoTime();
    }// end setEndTime method

    /*
     * getter method for endTime
     */
    public double getEndTime() { 
        return endTime;
    }// end getEndTime method

    /*
     * initialize method - initializes the user interface
     */
    public void intitialize() {

        welcomePrompt();

        //initialize Scanner object
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        setFileToRead(input.nextLine());//set file to read from user input

        //check if file exist
        File file = new File(getFileToRead()); // instantiate File object and pass it file path
        if(file.exists()){ // if file exists
            setStartTime(); // set start time
            menu(); // call selection menu
        }else{ // if file does not exist
            System.out.println("\n**File does not exist**");
            System.out.println("1). Enter 'Q' to Quit");
            System.out.println("2). Enter any charachter to re enter file path");
            System.out.print("Enter your selection: ");

            if(input.next().toUpperCase().compareTo("Q") != 0){ // user does not quit
                intitialize(); // call initialize method to re enter file path  
            }else{
                System.exit(0);
            }//end if

        }//end if
        input.close(); // close scanner

    }//end initialize method

    /*
     * welcomeScreen method - displays initial welcome screen and user prompts
     */
    public void welcomePrompt(){
        //user prompts
        System.out.println("\n*** Welcome to The US Crime Statistical Application***\n");
        System.out.println(" - Please enter the file path to start.");
        System.out.println(" - Please use / as path seperator: Example C:/user/file");
        System.out.print("File: ");

    }// end welcomePrompt method

    /*
     * menu method - displays menu of options
     */
    public void menu() {
        System.out.println(CLEANSPACE);
        System.out.println("******************** Welcome to The US Crime Statistical Application ********************");
        System.out.println("\n\nEnter the number of the question you want answered. Enter 'Q' to quit the program:\n");
        System.out.println("1. What were growth percentages in population growth for each consecutive year from 1994 - 2013?");
        System.out.println("2. What year was the Murder rate the highest?");
        System.out.println("3. What year was the Murder rate the lowest?");
        System.out.println("4. What year was the Robbery rate the highest?");
        System.out.println("5. What year was the Robbery rate the lowest?");
        System.out.println("Q. Quit the program");  
        System.out.print("\nEnter your selection: ");
        userSelection();//call user selection
    }// end menu method

    /*
     * userSelection method - gets user input selection from menu items
     */
    public void userSelection() {

        // declare variables
        String userInput; // holds user selection

        // initialize Scanner object
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        userInput = input.next().toUpperCase(); // assign user input to variable
        statisticSelection(userInput); // pass user input to statisticSelection method 
        input.close(); // close scanner

    }//end userSelection method

    /*
     * secondOptionSelection method - gets user input continue or quit prompt
     *                                that shows after first statistic is displayed
     */
    public void optionToQuit() {

        //declare variables
        String userInput;

        //initialize scanner
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\nEnter 'C' for menu or 'Q' to quit");
        userInput = input.next().toUpperCase(); // get user selection

        //validate second option menu
        if(userInput.compareTo("C") == 0){ // if continue is selected
            menu(); // call menu to be displayed
        }else if (userInput.compareTo("Q") == 0){ // if quit is selected
            statisticSelection(userInput);// pass user selection to switch statement in statistic selection
        }else{ // if invalid entry
            System.out.println("**Invalid selection - Returning to menu**.\n\n\n\n");
            menu(); // call menu to be displayed
        }//end if
        input.close(); // close scanner

    }//end userSelection method

    /*
     * statisticSelection method - takes the user input and calls the method to 
     *                             display statistics   
     */
    public void statisticSelection(String seclection){

        // declare variables
        boolean askContinue = false; //used to validate if continue or quit menu should be displayed

        // instantiate CrimeStatistic object 
        CrimeStatistics statistic = new CrimeStatistics();

        System.out.println(CLEANSPACE); //create space in output

        // switch statement to select correct statistic to be displayed
        switch(seclection){
            case "1":  ArrayList<String> growthRateChart = statistic.popGrowthRate(); // population growth rate chart
                        for(String year : growthRateChart)
                            System.out.println(year);
                        askContinue = true;
                        break;
            case "2": System.out.println(statistic.murderRateHigh()); // year of highest murder rate
                        askContinue = true;
                        break;
            case "3": System.out.println(statistic.murderRateLow()); // year of lowest murder rate
                        askContinue = true;
                        break;
            case "4": System.out.println(statistic.robberyRateHigh()); // year of highest robbery rate
                        askContinue = true;
                        break;
            case "5": System.out.println(statistic.robberyRateLow()); // year of lowest robbery rate
                        askContinue = true;
                        break;
            case "Q":   setEndTime(); // user quits - set end time
                        System.out.println(elsapsedTime()); //output elapsed time
                        System.exit(0); // exit 
                        break;
            case "C": menu(); // continue to menu of selections
                        break;
            default: System.out.println("\n\n**Invalid Entry. Please re enter your selection**\n"); // if user makes invalid selection  
                        menu(); // call selection menu
                        break;
        }//end switch statement

        // if a statistic has been called then display continue or quit
        if(askContinue){ // if boolean has been triggered from statistic being selected
            optionToQuit(); // call continue or quit
            askContinue = false; //re set boolean
        }//end if
    }//end userInput method

    /*
     * elapsedTime method - calculates and returns elapsed time
     */
    public String elsapsedTime(){
        double time = (getEndTime() - getStartTime())/1000000000.0; // calculate elapsed time
        String elapsedTime = ("\n***Elapsed Time: " + Math.round(time) + " seconds***\n");
        elapsedTime += "***Thank you for using the US Crime Statistics Program***\n\n";

        return elapsedTime;
    }// end elapsedTime method

}// end userInterface Class

/*
 * Class TestUserInterface - tests the UserInterface class and runs the program
 */
public class TestUserInterface {

    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args){

        //instantiate UserInterface object
        UserInterface userInterface = new UserInterface();
        userInterface.intitialize();// call initialization method


    }//end main

}// end TestUserInterface class

public class CrimeDataObjects {

    //declare variables
    private int year = 0; //year
    private double poplulation = 0; //population
    private long violentCrime = 0; //violent crime
    private float violentCrimeRate = 0; //violent crime rate
    private int murderNonNegManslaughter = 0; //Murder and non-negligent manslaughter
    private float murderNonNegManslaughterRate = 0;//Murder and non-negligent manslaughter rate
    private int rape = 0;//rape
    private float rapeRate = 0;//rape rate
    private int robbery = 0; //robbery
    private float robberyRate = 0;//robbery rate
    private int aggravatedAssault = 0;//Aggravated assault
    private float aggravatedAssaultRate = 0;//Aggravated assault rate
    private int propertyCrime = 0;//Property crime
    private float propertyCrimeRate = 0;//Property crime rate
    private int burglary = 0; //Burglary
    private float burglaryRate = 0;//Burglary rate
    private int larceny = 0;//larceny
    private float larcenyRate = 0;//larceny rate
    private int motorVehicleTheft = 0;//motor vehicle theft
    private float motorVehicleTheftRate = 0;//motor vehicle theft rate

    //default constructor
    public CrimeDataObjects(){  
    }

    //constructor 
    public CrimeDataObjects(int year, double poplulation, long vCrime, float vCrimeRate, 
                          int murderNonNegMan, float murderNonNegManRate, int rape, 
                          float rapeRate, int robbery,float robberyRate, int aggAssault, 
                          float aggAssaultRate, int propCrime, float propCrimeRate, int burglery, 
                          float burgleryRate,int larceny, float larcenyRate, int mvTheft, float mvTheftRate ) {

        this.year = year;
        this.poplulation = poplulation;
        this.violentCrime = vCrime;
        this.violentCrimeRate = vCrimeRate;
        this.murderNonNegManslaughter = murderNonNegMan;
        this.murderNonNegManslaughterRate = murderNonNegManRate;
        this.rape = rape;
        this.rapeRate = rapeRate;
        this.robbery = robbery;
        this.robberyRate = robberyRate;
        this.aggravatedAssault = aggAssault;
        this.aggravatedAssaultRate = aggAssaultRate;
        this.propertyCrime = propCrime;
        this.propertyCrimeRate = propCrimeRate;
        this.burglary = burglery;
        this.burglaryRate = burgleryRate;
        this.larceny = larceny;
        this.larcenyRate = larcenyRate;
        this.motorVehicleTheft =mvTheft;
        this.motorVehicleTheftRate = mvTheftRate;   
    }

    /*
     * getter method for year
     */
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }


    /*
     * getter method for population
     */
    public double getPoplulation() {
        return poplulation;
    }


    /*
     * getter method for violentCrime
     */
    public long getViolentCrime() {
        return violentCrime;
    }

    /*
     * getter method for violentCrimeRate
     */
    public float getViolentCrimeRate() {
        return violentCrimeRate;
    }

    /*
     * getter method for murderNonNegManslaughter
     */
    public int getMurderNonNegManslaughter() {
        return murderNonNegManslaughter;
    }

    /*
     * getter method for murderNonNegManslaughterRate
     */
    public float getMurderNonNegManslaughterRate() {
        return murderNonNegManslaughterRate;
    }

    /*
     * getter method for rape
     */
    public int getRape() {
        return rape;
    }


    /*
     * getter method for rapeRate
     */
    public float getRapeRate() {
        return rapeRate;
    }

    /*
     * getter method for robbery
     */
    public int getRobbery() {
        return robbery;
    }

    /*
     * getter method for robberyRate
     */
    public float getRobberyRate() {
        return robberyRate;
    }

    /*
     * getter method for aggravatedAssault
     */
    public int getAggravatedAssault() {
        return aggravatedAssault;
    }

    /*
     * getter method for aggravatedAssaultRate
     */
    public float getAggravatedAssaultRate() {
        return aggravatedAssaultRate;
    }


    /*
     * getter method for propertyCrime
     */
    public int getPropertyCrime() {
        return propertyCrime;
    }

    /*
     * getter method for propertyCrimeRate
     */
    public float getPropertyCrimeRate() {
        return propertyCrimeRate;
    }

    /*
     * getter method for burglary
     */
    public int getBurglery() {
        return burglary;
    }

    /*
     * getter method for burgleryRate
     */
    public float getBurgleryRate() {
        return burglaryRate;
    }

    /*
     * getter method for larceny
     */
    public int getLarceny() {
        return larceny;
    }

    /*
     * getter method for larcenyRate
     */
    public float getLarcenyRate() {
        return larcenyRate;
    }

    /*
     * getter method for motorVehicleTheft
     */
    public int getMotorVehicleTheft() {
        return motorVehicleTheft;
    }

    /*
     * getter method for motorVehicleTheftRate
     */
    public float getMotorVehicleTheftRate() {
        return motorVehicleTheftRate;
    }

}// end CrimeDataObjects cla
```

ss

Comment: **Advice** One: Learn to use a debugger. Two: Print `fileToRead` before you attempt to open it. Three: Do **not** make `fileToRead` `static`. Four: Do **not** post so much code, edit it into a Minimal, Reproducible Example. There is nothing about this that is minimal.

Comment: If you're seeing errors, it's helpful to post what errors you're actually seeing. And don't post the entire code base, find the relevant part of the code and post that so others can help you more easily.

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] instead of dumping all your code here having others sort through it.